# Cannot use $this in second class after including in main file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to bring my method into my main file , but I get this error:

`Using $this when not in object context`

I am developing a plugin for wordpress and i want to split in multiple classes , but when I bring all of them together I get some errors. I don't want to use composer even it will be easier to manipulate classes , but I want to simplify my plugin.
Thank you.

**main.php**

```
if ( !class_exists ('SS_Main') ):
    class SS_Main {
        
        /**
         * Plugin Basename;
        */
        protected static $plugin;
        
        function __construct() {
             self::$plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
        }
                

        
    }
    
    // main instance;
    $ss_instance = new SS_Main();

    // settings core;
    require_once SS_PLUGIN_PATH . 'inc/base/settings.php';
    $settings_instance = new Settings();
    $settings_instance->register_pages();
```

**settings.php**

```
class Settings {
    
    public $admin_pages = array();
    public $admin_subpages = array();
    
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->admin_pages = array(
            array(
                'page_title'  => 'Dashboard',
                'menu_title'  => 'Dashboard',
                'capability'  => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug'   => SS_PLUGIN,
                'callback'    => 'dashboard_template',
                'icon_url'    => 'dashicons-store',
                'position'    => 55
            )
        );
        
    }

    public function register_pages(){
        if( !empty( $this->admin_pages ) ):
            add_action('admin_menu', array('Settings', 'add_admin_menu'));
        endif;
    }
    
    public function add_admin_menu(){
        // here I get the error...
        foreach( $this->admin_pages as $page ):
            add_menu_page (
                $page['page_title'],
                $page['menu_title'],
                $page['capability'],
                $page['menu_slug'],
                $page['callback'],
                $page['icon_url'],
                $page['position']
            );
        endforeach; 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The reason you are getting this error, is `add_action('admin_menu', array('Settings', 'add_admin_menu'))` - you passed the class _name_ as the first value of your callable here, which means it will treat it as a _static_ method call. And in static methods (or non-static methods called _as_ static), you can't use $this.

Comment: If you _want_ this to call the method on the `Settings` _instance_, then you should pass `$this` instead of the class name, in _that_ place to begin with.

Comment: What he means is add_action('admin_menu, array( $this, 'add_admin_menu'));

Comment: Thank you all guys.. I didn't payed attention to this thing.